# Where does the Lone Gunmen Series fit into the X-Files continuity?

Tags: the-x-files, the-lone-gunmen

I'm trying to watch *The X-Files* from the beginning to end. (I am currently at the beginning of Season 3.) I want to watch *The Lone Gunmen* series too. But I want to avoid any X-Files spoilers if possible.

Is there anything in *The Lone Gunmen* series that would be a spoiler for *The X-Files*? I know that *The Lone Gunmen* collection includes the episode of *The X-Files* that wraps up their story, but if I avoid that, am I safe from spoilers?

Answer (score 3):

There are no X-Files spoilers in Lone Gunmen. The reverse is not true, massively so. Make sure that you watch the entirety of Lone Gunmen before you continue past the wrap-up episode with X-Files.

Comment: the above answer is rubbish... what people are seeking is the sequence of the episodes threaded into the xfiles.. Does anyone know up to what episode of the xfiles you should watch before staring the lone rangers.

Comment: The question text has been updated since I answered it -the original question was ”Does the Lone Gunman series contain any spoilers for X-files.” I concur that my answer had been abnegated by the update...

Comment: On Quora there would be a small note stating the title you replied to, if it had been edited after you answered. Maybe SE should adopt such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that it's too late for the original poster to answer this question but here goes:

As per the previous answer there are no spoilers in the Lone Gunmen for the X-Files so you could safely watch all Lone Gunmen episodes in complete safety.

However, the reverse is not true.

The Lone Gunmen series was crudely cancelled after 13 episodes. Although it didn't contain any massive cliffhangers that needed clearing up the characters were much loved so a 'Wrap-up' episode [Jump the shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_the_Shark_(The_X-Files)) aired in Season 9 (episode 15) which conslusively ended the Lone Gunmen series. This episode while revisiting the characters shared between the X-Files and the Lone gunmen also includes two characters from the Lone gunmen, Yves Adele Harlow & [Jimmy Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Bond) neither of whom have previously appeared in the X-Files.

So, the advice is, watch the Lone Gunmen series immediately before watching the 'Jump the shark' episode of the X-Files.

As a footnote, the x-files season 7 episode 9 - [Millenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(The_X-Files)) 'wraps-up' the television series [Millenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(TV_series)) so it is also advisable to watch the TV series before the X-Files episode.